# what to do when your WordPress database is too large?

Tags: database, mysql

Well I have asked this question in WP Forums, StackOverflow, and GoDaddy community as well, but nothing worked out. Hoping something is in here.

I used 2 separated subdomains for my blog and site (2separate SQL database). But not I cudn't maintain separately so trying to merge them into a single WP driven site. If I do that, I will end up with limitation of max 1GB SQL DB set by GoDaddy (and I can't purchase dedicated solutions for this).

There is a way out to split a single DB into 2, or use more than 1 DB for WP. So, asking for you genius guys to help me out.

Comment: Use a host that isn't garbage...

Comment: 1GB is a large database, how many posts / pages have you got?!

Answer (score 5):

Not 100% sure how your DB could get that big. Have you gone through and cleaned out post revisions, old rows in the wp_options table from old plugins, etc?

Comment: simply because of many posts and drafts, the database is larger.

Comment: that's still very, VERY large. I have a site with over 2700 posts and the database isn't that large. I'd first go and make sure all post revisions are removed.

Answer (score 3):

I have a working solution but it could seems a bit hackish.
Put this code inside your wp-config.php and have fun!
Note: You need to remove other occurences of  define('DB_NAME') etc.

```
switch($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])
{
 case 'blog.example.com': 
{
    define('DB_NAME', 'database_1');
    define('DB_USER', 'user_for_db1');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', 'pwd_for_db1');
    define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
    break;
}
 case 'www.example.com': 
{
    define('DB_NAME', 'database_2');
    define('DB_USER', 'user_for_db2');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', 'pwd_for_db2');
    define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
    break;
}
```

The code above checks for $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] variable and switch db connection according to it.

Hope this helps!